# Can I reference a complete Ruby Net::HTTP request as a string before sending?

Tags: ruby, http, ruby-1.9.2, net-http

I'm using `Net::HTTP` in Ruby 1.9.2p290 to handle some, obviously, networking calls.

I now have a need to see the complete request that is sent to the server (as one long big String conforming to HTTP 1.0/1.1.

In other words, I want `Net::HTTP` to handle the heavy lifting of generating the HTTP standard-compliant request+body, but I want to send the string with a custom delivery mechanism.

`Net::HTTPRequest` doesn't seem to have any helpful methods here -- do I need to go lower down the stack and hijack something?

Does anyone know of a good library, maybe other than Net::HTTP, that could help?

*EDIT*:  I'd also like to do the same going the other way (turning a string response into `Net::HTTP::*` -- although it seems I may be able to instantiate `Net::HTTPResponse` by myself?

Answer (score 2):

Request:

```
post = Net::HTTP::Post.new('http://google.com')
post.set_form_data :query => 'ruby http'
sio = StringIO.new
post.exec si, Net::HTTP::HTTPVersion, post.path
puts sio.string
```

Response:

```
si = StringIO.new("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
bio = Net::BufferedIO.new(si)
Net::HTTPResponse.read_new(bio)
```

Comment: Seems very close.  I'm using the Response code you've offered, but I'm getting - `NoMethodError: undefined method 'closed?' for nil:NilClass` when I call `read_new`.  Particularly when I am parsing an HTTP response with no body.  Also, when I have a string with no headers, `headers` is nil, instead of [] as I'd expect.

Comment: OH, and I forgot to say - THANKS!  This is bringing me much closer.

Comment: Well, I figured out the second issue - it's `header`, not `headers` ;)